# php pdo fetchall() returns the value 'array' when using print_r

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to get all of a user's friend requests and display them. However, print_r only prints 'array' on to the screen. When I use print/echo and the array index (eg. $arrayname[0]) it works. However, it only works for the first (0) value of the index. The rest arent displayed (eg. $arrayname[0] returns a value but $arrayname[1] doesnt), even though there are multiple values in the database. Here's my code

```
 $fr_requests = $db->prepare("SELECT uid, requester, date_requested FROM friends WHERE rid= :uid AND accepted= 'c'");
        $fr_requests-> bindParam(':uid', $user_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $fr_requests->execute();
        $request_count = $fr_requests->rowCount();
        if($request_count == 0) {
            $_SESSION['no_fr_requests'] = "1";
            } else {
        $req_person_id = $fr_requests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
        $req_person_name = $fr_requests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
        $date_requested = $fr_requests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 2);
        $_SESSION['fr_requests_count'] = $request_count;
        $_SESSION['req_person_id'] = $req_person_id;
        $_SESSION['req_person_name'] = $req_person_name;
        $_SESSION['date_requested'] = $date_requested;
        print ($request_count.'<br>');
        print_r ($req_person_id.'<br>');
        print_r ($req_person_name.'<br>');
        print_r ($date_requested.'<br>');
        }
```

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `var_dump()` instead of `print_r`

Comment: @zerkms this is what I get when I used var_dump    array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "200" } array(0) { } array(0) { }

Comment: So? The first thing you passed is an array with one element, the other two are empty arrays. The thing is - you cannot call `fetchAll` several times, it makes no sense.

Comment: Also your concatenating the array with '<br>' ... so string = error (array to string)

Comment: @zerkms But they're not empty arrays. And the fist array with the value "200" in the 0 index should have a value of "29" in the 1 index. Is my fetchall() code right?

Comment: They are empty arrays. Just switch to `$data = $fr_requests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and work with `$data`

Comment: @zerkms Ok, but how do I get the individual columns from the $data variable?

Comment: @user4559334 it's a normal array. So you work with it like with any other array.

Comment: @zerkms This is what I get. array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["uid"]=> string(3) "200" ["requester"]=> string(9) "Test data" ["date_requested"]=> string(19) "2015-02-22 16:25:34" } }  It still doesnt get the other rows

Comment: @zerkms nvm. Thanks for all your help. It was my mistake, the other row didn't match the SELECT statement requirements. But your method works perfectly.